# Rails High_Voltage error: undefined method 'page_path' for #<#<Class:.....>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, static-pages, high-voltage

I used to link to static pages with a dedicated controller / view for each of them but, of course, this is odd.
I just installed the High_Voltage gem in my Rails (Rails 5.1.7 on Debian) app in order to create simpler, easily readable links. 
I successfully routed: 
`page GET    /pages/*id    high_voltage/pages#show` 
and in my application.html.erb I included: 
`<%  link_to "About", page_path(:id =>"about") %>`

.../app/views/pages/about.html.erb exists - but I don't even get there, because Rails replies with a

```
NoMethodError in Welcome#index: undefined method 'page_path' for "#<#<Class:.....>
```

What's my new-bee mistake? Any hint is highly appreciated. Thanks!!
Karsten

Answer (score 1):

I found out: after installation, I need to restart the puma server. That's it!